# How does findViewById works on a multi hierarchy tree with many IDs from a Custom View?

Tags: android, tree

I have a quite complex View with many hierarchies. Within that, I have a CustomView called ExpandableText, in which I have a RelativeLayout and a TextView inside it with "expandable_text" as ID.

In my main view, I'm creating multiple instances of ExpandableView with the code:

```
<include layout="@layout/expandable_text"
         android:id="@+id/expandable1"
/>
<include layout="@layout/expandable_text"
         android:id="@+id/expandable2"
/>
<include layout="@layout/expandable_text"
         android:id="@+id/expandable3"
/>
```

These ExpandableViews are within a LinearLayout. At some point I got the reference to the LinearLayout, and wanted to access all three expandable_texts within my custom view.

In this case, how does findViewById() work?

I mean, my hierarchy is basically:

ParentViews... > LinearLayout > 3 ExpandableViews > RelativeLayout > TextView

where these TextViews have the same ID, and each ExpandableView has a different ID.

I looked on google and couldn't find much of how this DOM structure works. From [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html):

> View IDs need not be unique throughout the tree, but it is good
>   practice to ensure that they are at least unique within the part of
>   the tree you are searching.

And on this [topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/ke-0moeppL0) someone said:

> It's not random at all. findViewById() is a depth-first search 
>   algorithm; it will return the first view of the specified id it can 
>   find.

Is it correct? I mean, I basically created this topic out of curiosity of how the Android "DOM traversing" works, and I'd appreciate if someone could clarify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it correct?

Yes, that's how it will work. It would find the `TextView` within the first expandable view. To narrow it down, in this case, what you would want to do is first find the unique expandable row, and from *that* view, look for the `TextView`. For instance, assuming your `TextView`'s ID is `my_textview` and you want to find that view within the second row:

```
View expandedRow2 = findViewByid(R.id.expandable2);
TextView textView2 = (TextView) expandedRow2.findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
```

Comment: Thanks! After a few NullPointer and ClassCast Exceptions I made my code work and managed to test it. When calling the expandable_text within the parent view it found the first occurrence, which was inside expandable_text1. So, summarizing what I just learned: findViewById makes a depth search and returns the first match, and getParent() returns the immediate parentView of a View. Sounds like traversing in Android is pretty simple now. :)